# Unpredictable nil check result

Tags: swift, dictionary

Unpredictable (unobvious) `nil` check:

this function:

```
fileprivate func isPurchased(_ name: String) -> Bool {
        if let _ = dictionary[name] {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

returns `true` for:

`fileprivate var dictionary = [String: Double?]()`

and `false` for `[String: Double]` (that's normal). Why?

I initialize `dictionary` like this:

`dictionary["test"] = nil`

I mean:

`isPurchased("test")` returns `true` for `[String: Double?]`

and

`isPurchased("test")` returns `false` for `[String: Double]`

**UPDATE**

```
 var dictionary = [String: Double?]()
dictionary["test"] = nil
print("\(isPurchased("test"))")
```

prints `true`

```
 var dictionary = [String: Double]()
dictionary["test"] = nil
print("\(isPurchased("test"))")
```

prints `false`

why?

Comment: Please show the entire code - for which value of `name` and which content and type of  `dictionary` does `isPurchased` return *what*?

Comment: @luk2302 , I wrote. `dictionary["test"] = nil` . isPurchased("test") returns `true` in case ` [String: Double?]()`

Comment: @luk2302 , updated a bit

Comment: But I cannot test that code, there is no reason to describe your code, just write the actual code that produces the output and then write in a comment what the output is - then state what is confusing about that.

Comment: @luk2302 , please, look

Comment: Your first example prints false for me (as I would expect, as Swift should infer the `nil` to be a `Double??.none`). Although you should always steer clear of dictionaries with optional values as you can very easily get into a mess with double wrapped optionals. Just use a dictionary with a non-optional `Value`, and simply use `nil` to indicate the lack of a value for a given key.

Comment: You are bypassing the dictionary definition that dictionaries must/should not contain `nil` values. As you allow `nil` values in the first example it returns true. I wish the Swift developers forbid optional values in dictionaries. By definition a `nil` value in a dictionary indicates *key is missing*.

Comment: For your first example, the `[String: Double?]` dict., note that `Double?` is just syntactic sugar for `Optional<Double>`. Use this fact to explicitly type out what `.none` (`nil`) you are assigning to `dictionary["test"]`; this approach will make this question quite self-explanatory. Assigning `Optional<Double>.none` will yield a `true` return (as this is a valid element of type `Optional<Double>`), whereas assigning `Optional<Optional<Double>>.none` will yield a `false` return. Ponder over the difference of these two in the context of assigning a `nil` value for a given (existing) dict. key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use if let to check if something's nil. Just use `value == nil`

As discussed in the comments, getting the value with the subscript from a dictionary of type `[String: Double?]` results in a double-optional (`Double??`).

This means `dictionary[name]` has a value of `Optional.some(Optional.none)`.

To get around this, you can do something like:

```
if let value = dictionary["test"], value != nil
```